# MySQL DELETE query doesn't delete element from c++ code

Tags: c++, mysql

I have this simple code:

```
    std::stringstream del;
    int ret = 0;
    del<<"DELETE FROM 'database_name' WHERE id=\""<<id<<"\""; //id is a parameter of the function
    std::string query = del.str();
    const char* ch_q = query.c_str();
    ret = mysql_query(conn, ch_q);
    if(ret == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Record deleted successfully"<<std::endl;
        return true;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"Failed to delete record"<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```

The `id` row in the database has a type of `TEXT` and is a `PRIMARY KEY`
Every time I run the code, it fails to delete the element.

Comment: Have you queried the MySQL library for the exact error message?

Comment: Have you considered using parameters? Building SQL like this is usually bad.

Comment: Do you really have single quotes around the table's name?

Comment: "It fails to delete the element" And does it report any error? If so, what? It presumably does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement has an error where you're naming the table.

From [the MySQL manual page on identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html):

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`)

So:

```
DELETE FROM `database_name`
```

You've used a single-quote instead:

```
DELETE FROM 'database_name'
```